# How can i use Array includes() Method to check value exist in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code which get all the data in kendo grid column `Type`. how can I check if array contain `Type ='Custom Document'`?

I tried the following

```
function chkCustomDocumentIncluded() {
    var messageText = '';

    var arrayType = [];
    var data = $("#CustomDocumentsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        arrayType.push(data[i].Type);          
    }       
    if (arrayType.includes("Custom SBA")) {
        messageText = '@Localizer["Custom document is required"].Value';
    }

    return messageText;
}
```

`console.log(arrayType)` returns expected value but how can i add a condition to check the value exist?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: Show an example of the value of `arrayType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check if every element of the array meets a condition.

```
function chkCustomDocumentIncluded() {
    var data = $("#CustomDocumentsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;
    if (!data || data.every(d => d.Type == "Custom SBA")) {
        return '@Localizer["Custom document is required"].Value';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Custom SBA` the exact value of the `Type` property? Or is it a substring?

Comment: I think its working let me try it again, is there anyways to check when the grid is empty?

Comment: its working but doesnt check when array or grid is null or empty

Comment: I've updated it to check that `data` is not null before searching it.

Comment: What is `grid`? I assumed you meant `data`.

Comment: yes data sorry, also it only check if `Custom SBA` the first item in data

Comment: My answer will return an empty string if `data` is null. Should it return the error message instead?

Comment: Barmar, I want check the whole array check Custom SBA exist

Comment: That's what this does. If the array is not null, and the string exists anywhere in the array, it returns the error message.

Comment: Do you want to check if *all* of them are `Custom SBA`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes that what i am looking thanks! and validation message `Custom document is required` if Custom SBA doesn't exist in the list, if one `Custom SBA` no validation message

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the `every()` method.